# Undefined behavior in std::uninitialized_default_construct example on cppreference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic, placement-new

In their [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_default_construct) of `std::uninitialized_default_construct`:

```
    struct S { std::string m{ "Default value" }; };
 
    constexpr int n {3};
    alignas(alignof(S)) unsigned char mem[n * sizeof(S)];
 
    try
    {
        auto first {reinterpret_cast<S*>(mem)};
        auto last {first + n};  // (1)**********
 
        std::uninitialized_default_construct(first, last);

        // (2)**********
        for (auto it {first}; it != last; ++it) {
            std::cout << it->m << '\n';
        }
 
        std::destroy(first, last);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception!\n";
    }
 
    // Notice that for "trivial types" the uninitialized_default_construct
    // generally does not zero-fill the given uninitialized memory area.
    int v[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    const int original[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::uninitialized_default_construct(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

    // (3)**********
    // for (const int i : v) { std::cout << i << ' '; }
    // Maybe undefined behavior, pending CWG 1997.
```

I have three questions. **(Mark as ********** )**

1. Since `S` and `unsigned char` aren't **pointer-interconvertible**, will `last` point to past-the-end of `mem`? Is pointer arithmetic undefined behavior here?
2. Is **std::launder** needed here to make `first` and `last` actually point to `S`? e.g. `first = std::launder(first); last = first + n;`
3. Is it really undefined behavior to print elements of `v`? [CWG 1997](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1997) talk about `unsigned char[]` storage, but the above example has initialized `v` with `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `unsigned char` is another way of saying `1 byte`, so the allocation is performed for the size of the `struct S` (in bytes) multiplied by the number of elements `n`. The `mem` is of type `unsigned char []`, therefore, as per [[conv.array]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array#1) it will be equivalent of `unsigned char *` which points to the first element in the array, and as per [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4) the `reinterpret_cast` will convert it to `struct S*` which will cause the `first`, which is declared as `auto` to be created as a `struct S*`, so the statement is interchangeable with the `C` form:

   ```
   struct S* first = (struct S*) &mem
   ```

   Since the `first` is resolved as `struct S*`, therefore the `last` will also be resolved to the same type and the pointer arithmetic will work fine.
2. There is no need for the `std::launder` since the statement `auto first {reinterpret_cast<S*>(mem)};` already had initialized the pointer to the first element in `mem`, and the next statement with the pointer arithmetic already set the `last` to the 3rd element.
3. I think this is correct that this is undefined behavior as of [CWG 1997](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1997). The `int []`, which is the type of `v`, has no default constructor, therefore the `v` can not be initialized. As per definition, the values will remain undetermined. The confusing part is that elements of `v` are already initialized by the compiler to the `1, 2, 3, 4`, so expectation is that this values will be preserved (as they are already in the memory location), however from the standard perspective there is no determination if `v` will maintain this values after the `std::uninitialized_default_construct(std::begin(v), std::end(v))`.

Comment: "The `reinterpret_cast` will cause the first, which is declared as `auto` to be created as a `struct S*`"  unfortunately, `S` has a non-trivial destructor, preventing it from being an implicit-lifetime class per [\[class.prop\]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#9).

Comment: @L.F. even if  `S` were ILT, `reinterpret_cast` wouldn't produce a pointer to an object of type `S` from a pointer to `unsigned char`

Comment: @L.F. as per [\[class.dtor\]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#2), in case where the prospective destructor is omitted, the same will be implicitly declared.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski Yes, but the implicitly declared destructor is non-trivial because the destructor of `string` is.

Comment: @L.F. I see the point, but this I don't see how it relates to the `std::uninitialized_default_construct()` example. The cast in the example works because both (the lvalue and the rvalue) are interpreted as pointers.

Comment: _the pointer arithmetic will work fine_ The standard says: _`uninitialized_default_construct(NoThrowForwardIterator first, NoThrowForwardIterator last)` Equivalent to: `for (; first != last; ++first) ...`_ and since `first` points to an object of type `unsigned char` having type «pointer to `S`», doing `++first` is UB because of [\[expr.add\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#6.sentence-1).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer the ` [\[expr.add\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#6.sentence-1) is related to `p + q`, where `typeid(p)` != `typeid(q)`. In this case we have `p + (p)1`, or `++p` so both are same type. Also, `first` doesn't point to `unsigned char` (although the arithmetic would still work, but it would produce wrong memory address), `first` points to `struct S`.

Comment: "In this case we have `p + (p)1`"  Not really.  What we have is `p + 1`, where `p` is a pointer type and `1` is an integer.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you were serous writing the last comment.

Comment: Let me clarify, from [\[expr.add\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#4) If `p` points to an element `i` in an array (which is always the implicit case), adding integer `j` is interpreted as a moving the pointer to hypothetical `i+j` element. So saying `first = first+1` means to move pointer `first` to point to the next element of the array. `first` is implicitly a pointer to the first element of the array dye to [\[conv.array\]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array#1). And due to the `reinterpred_cast<S*>`, `first` of type `struct S*`.

Comment: _`first` is implicitly a pointer to the first element of the array_ of `unsigned char[3 * sizeof(S)]` type. _And due to the `reinterpred_cast<S*>`, `first` of type `struct S*`_ And this is the problem. Using `first` in pointer arithmetic would violate [expr.add]/6.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I understand your point, but this is not the case. `first` is `struct S*` not `unsigned char *`. I think the confusion is due to the type inference. The `auto` keyword, will construct `first` as per the return type of `reinterpret_cast<S*>` as specified in [\[dcl.spec.auto.general\]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto.general#4). `reinterpret_cast<T>` has a `T` as a return type. Therefore, `first` has nothing to do with `unsigned char` and this is the whole reason that we need `reinterpred_cast<S*>`.

Comment: _I understand your point_ I don't think so. _`first` is `struct S*` not `unsigned char *`_ This is true. _I think the confusion is due to the type inference._ No. A prvalue [expression] (`first` is [converted to prvalue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/conv.lval) in `first + 1`, or at least should be, the standard has a defect here) has: 1) type; 2) value. The type is `struct S*`. The value is «pointer to the first element of `mem`» (which is of `unsigned char` type). `reinterpred_cast<S*>(mem)` doesn't change the value of the expression `mem`, only the type...

Comment: ... Using an expression with incoherent type and value in pointer arithmetic is UB because you know why.

Comment: I think the problem that @LanguageLawyer is trying to point out here is that, for `first + 1` to attain defined behavior, where `first` is of type `S*`, it is necessary that `first` "points to an array element `i` of an array object `x` with `n` elements" per [\[expr.add\]/4.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2), which is not the case with `first`, being produced by `reinterpret_cast`ing a pointer to the first element of an array of `unsigned char` per [\[expr.reinterpret.cast\]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) instead of actually pointing to an object of type `S`.

Comment: In other words, during this whole process, there is never an `S` object to start with.

Comment: @L.F. There may be an `S` object, because any array is ILT and `S[3]` may be implicitly created in `mem`. But `reinterpret_cast<S*>(mem)` just can't reach the first element of this implicitly created array.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I keep hitting the limits of my knowledge on the new lifetime-related stuff - I'll just leave this one to you :)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer After `first = std::launder(first);` , is pointer arithmetic  `last = first + n;` defined behavior thanks to ILT `S[3]`?

Comment: @DanShen `std::launder` requires an object to be within lifetime, but, even though array `S[3]` is withing lifetime, its elements are not, because `S` is not an ILT. Using `launder` in such a way is UB because it violates Preconditions. (It is a bit circular. ILT objects are created if creating them would make a program have defined behavior. Since a program would have UB if `S[3]` were created, `S[3]` is not even created).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer and @L.F. I agree that the example is "strange" and more suited for a `C` example, however it's perfectly aligned with the standards. The `first` and `mem` have nothing in common from the language perspective. We used `reitnerpret_cat<S*>`, which part of the standard, to force the compiler to get the pointer to first element of `mem` and move it to `first` disregarding the type safety checks. So yes, the key point here is that `reitnerpret_cat<S*>` doesn't change the value of `mem` it only assigns the address of `mem` to `first` with new type, and this is why the example works.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer If `std::uninitialized_default_construct(first, last);` this line in the example is replace by e.g. 
```
for (auto it = mem; it != std::end(mem); it += sizeof(S)) { ::new(static_cast<void*>(it))S; }
```
then
```
first = std::launder(first);  last = first + n;
```
will be defined behavior, right?

Comment: @DanShen looks like it will.